# Explode php array then if value exists echo something

Tags: php, explode

Here's what I have as a result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => goodytwoshoes00newyiala
            [identifier] => goodytwoshoes00newyiala
            [1] => Abbyy GZ;Animated GIF;Archive BitTorrent;Book Cover Image;DjVu;DjVuTXT;Djvu XML;EPUB;Grayscale LuraTech PDF;MARC;Metadata;Scribe Scandata Zip;Single Page Processed JP2 ZIP;Single Page Raw JP2 ZIP;Text PDF
            [format] => Abbyy GZ;Animated GIF;Archive BitTorrent;Book Cover Image;DjVu;DjVuTXT;Djvu XML;EPUB;Grayscale LuraTech PDF;MARC;Metadata;Scribe Scandata Zip;Single Page Processed JP2 ZIP;Single Page Raw JP2 ZIP;Text PDF
            [2] => 
            [creator
```

///

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

//= Closed while ====================//
/*everytime it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($result));

echo "<pre>";
//= Prints $r as array =================//
print_r ($r);
//=============================//
echo "</pre>";
```

I need to explode this and write an if "pdf" exists or if "raw JP2 exists" then echo something. But first I think I need to explode it but I'm not sure. It's been a long day and usually I can think through this and still might. but thought I would see if someone has done this before because I can't seem to find out how on stack.

Thanks

Brandon

Comment: Weird use of assignment of right into the arra. You are always going to end up with an array item with value `false` at the last index position.  Other than that not sure what you are getting at about exploding and PDF exists and such.  You don't show any code around it, so hard to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always do this:

```
foreach ($row as $val) {
    if (strpos($val['format'], 'PDF') !== false || strpos($val['format'], 'Raw JP2') !== false) {
        echo "some echo";
    }
}
```

You have to use the !== with strpos (which returns the position of an occurrence inside a string), because it returns a boolean false if it DOES NOT find it anywhere, but it returns integer 0 if it is at the beginning of the string.

You can use `stripos()` if you want it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Will try and let you know. TY :)